# Using directives in new files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, using-directives

Is it possible to have additional "using" directives automatically added to my new aspx.cs files so that I do not have to keep typing the same ones over and over again (i.e. custom namespace using directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the files that are used by the template.  Better yet, create your own.  File + Export Template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to type them in.  When writing the code, type in the name of the class (without the namespace).  Then hit `CTRL+.`.  That will open up the resolve type intellisense helper.  It will add the using statement to the top of the file.  No scrolling necessary.

Comment: I was thinking about using this method, but I have a helper, and he is not too familiar with using VS2008 or anytype of Development software expect for notepad. So I am a little reluctant